# Converting non-array value to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I'm working with Vue and in my data I have an array that can also contain other arrays.
My problem is that if something isn't represented as an array, I'd like to convert it to one.
For example:

```
my_array:Array[2]
  0:Reactive
    price_type: "Adult"
    price_layer:Array[3]
    price:Array[3]
  1:Reactive
    type: "Child"
    price_layer:Array[3]
    price: 30
```

In my second array exists 'price: 30'. I want it to read 'price: [30]' so that it's captured in a for loop I have running in Vue. Is there a way to accomplish this without reassigning it to a new var and keeping the rest of the data intact?

Comment: `[my_array[1].price]` will put it in an array.

Comment: And [`Array.isArray()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) will determine if a thing is an array *(not a typed array, e.g., `Int16Array`, but this is likely not in play here)*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a conditional expression to put the value in an array if it's not already an array.

```
my_array.forEach(el => 
  (Array.isArray(el.price) ? el.price : [el.price]).forEach(
    price => console.log(price)))
```